# Boost::asio  -- UnregisterWaitEx' has not been declared

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, serial-port

I'm trying to build a program that will be able to read and write to a Serial Port.
At the moment I am using a wrapper class that works with boost::asio. 
( http://gitorious.org/serial-port )

I'm getting a bunch of errors from win_object_handle_service.ipp (from boost asio)
The error Message i get is at http://pastebin.com/MtcC61cb

Additionally, in the AsyncSerial.hpp file from the SerialPort Library
I get an error on line 103:

```
thread t(boost::bind(&asio::io_service::run, &pimpl->io))
```

There is nothing in the compilers error log, but eclipse reports that:

1. boost::bind is ambiguous
2. invalid overload of 'asio::io_service::run'

I'm not sure if the above are valid errors, or if its just eclipse's indexer being stupid

My Question is:
Can anyone help to figure out why I am getting this error message, and how I can get my program to compile?

I'm also welcome to suggestions for a different Serial library.  However I would need it to be cross platform.

I'm running windows 7 x64 compiling with MinGW 4.7.1 (32 bit).

Comment: Ok,  Apparently I'm really bad at google.

http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/boost-asio-UnregisterWaitEx-RegisterWaitForSingleObject-has-not-been-declared-td4633963.html

The fix is to define the windows version with -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -DWINVER=0x0501.

Figures that I find the answer as soon as I submit the question.

Comment: 1) Your pastebin link is already dead. 2) You can post an answer to your own question, and accept it. This is the accepted thing to do if nobody else has posted the correct answer and you find it yourself. (Obviously don't do this if someone else has posted the answer you settle on.)

Comment: Downvote for using pastebin. The idea is to preserve knowledge on here to share for future problems - not to get quick personal help that is useless to others as soon as the link expires.

Comment: If you have a windows.h header before boost-asio make sure you switch them so the compiler can find winsock 2 over 1. Seemed to work for me.like this `#include <boost/asio.hpp> #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #include <windows.h>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem compiling the chat_client from the [boost examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html)

it was:

```
boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
```

and i changed it to use an explicit cast:

```
boost::thread t(boost::bind((unsigned long int (boost::asio::io_service::*)())&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
```

And the compile errors went away

Answer (score 0):

I found that to fix these ambiguities, you need to turn off Eclipse's added compile errors:

> Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Code Analysis.

Turn on `Use project settings`

Then disable the relevant Eclipse errors, eg. Ambiguity.